# How to get FormGroup inside Directive?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-directive

On an Angular 7 form I have:

```
<form [formGroup]="message" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" formControlName="name">
  <p class="error" *ngIf="message.get('name').errors">
    {{message.get('name')?.errors?.error}}
  </p>
</form>
```

I am showing the error paragraph if there is any error for field `name`.

Instead of repeating the error paragraph code I would prefer to use a simple directive:

```
<p class="error" formValidationName="name"></p>
```

I tried to create the directive:

```
@Directive({ selector: 'formValidationName' })

export class FormValidationNameDirective {

  constructor(el: ElementRef, renderer: Renderer) {

    renderer.setElementStyle(el.nativeElement, 'display', 'none');

    // Get formGroup

  }

}
```

How to get, inside the directive, the the formGroup in which the directive is in?

In this example would be the message formGroup.

I need this so in the directive template I can render:

```
  <p class="error" *ngIf="message.get('name').errors">
    {{message.get('name')?.errors?.error}}
  </p>
```

Where message is the FormGroup instance.

Comment: You can simply inject it in the constructor. But I strongly advise you to have a look at ngx-valdemort, which probably does what you want to achieve, and more (disclaimer: I wrote it): https://ngx-valdemort.ninja-squad.com/

Comment: @JBNizet is ngx-valdemort works with template driven forms too?

Comment: @robert Yep. https://github.com/Ninja-Squad/ngx-valdemort/blob/master/projects/ngx-valdemort/src/lib/validation-errors.component.spec.ts#L388-L418